# Find the maximum of $xy(72-3x-4y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$x$ and $y$ are positive. I have been stuck on this problem for a while now, any hints please?

Comment: I tried AM-GM (crashed and burned), I tried writing this as a quadratic of one variable, and I tried manipulating this any way I could to make the answer clear.

Comment: @Ovi AM-GM works. Hint multiply by 12.

Comment: @Ovi And for completeness, I added how to approach it as a quadratic in one variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $72-3x-4y\leq 0$, then the product is $\leq 0$, which clearly can't be the maximum.

**Hint:** Multiply by 12. Apply AM-GM to $3x, 4y, (72-3x-4y)$ (which are all positive)

> $$\sqrt[3]{12xy(72-3x-4y)} \leq \frac{ 3x + 4y + (72-3x-4y) } { 3} = 24. $$

---

**Hint:** Write it as a quadratic in one variable.

If $x$ is fixed, then let $72-3x = L$, and we want to maximize $y(L-4y) = -4y^2 + yL$. This achieves its maximum when $8y = L= 72-3x$.

If $y$ is fixed, then let $72-4y = K$, and we want to maximize $x(K-3x) = -3x^2 + xK$. This achieves its maximum when  $6x = K = 72-4y$.

Thus, this gives us $8y+3x = 72 = 6x+4y$, or that $4y=3x = 24$, which agrees with the AM-GM equality case.

Comment: Haha thanks I wish I could give you another +1. I actually got to $-4y^2+yL$ but for some unknown reason I did not continue, I guess I thought you couldn't that this as a normal quadratic since $x$ is still a variable, but I should've realized that it doesn't matter since it is still independent of $y$.

Comment: @Ovi well now that you learnt that, remember it. It's often useful to (temporarily) assume that one variable is fixed and manipulate the rest.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yup thank you I'll use that from now on

Comment: @CalvinLin: It is interesting to me that this function $f(x,y)=xy(72-3x-4y)$ can't use the routine way in which we find max or min. In fact in all critical points we see $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f^2_{xy}<0$.